# 404 error when using UrlBasedViewResolver and JstlView

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm creating a simple hello world application using maven and java-based configuration. However, I keep on getting a 404 error on a simple href link. The files are below.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is the Home Page</p>
    <a href="hello-page.html">Access Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**LinkController.java**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class LinkController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello-page")
    public ModelAndView showHelloPage(){

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        modelAndView.setViewName("hello");

        modelAndView.addObject("meow", "MEOW MEOW MEOW");

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**WebAppConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration                      //specifies that this is a configuration class
@ComponentScan("com.springtest")        //specifies which packages to scan
@EnableWebMvc                       //specifies that web-mvc annotations can be used
public class WebAppConfig {

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver(){
        UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();

        urlBasedViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        urlBasedViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        urlBasedViewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

        return urlBasedViewResolver;
    }

}
```

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(WebAppConfig.class);

        context.setServletContext(servletContext);

        Dynamic servletDynamic =  servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(context));

        //dispatcher servlet will handle all requests
        servletDynamic.addMapping("/");

        servletDynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>mavenDWP</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

my webapp folder looks like:
[image: my webapp folder looks like:]

Comment: You're building your `DispatcherServlet` in `WebAppInitializer`, but I'm not seeing anywhere that that class is getting invoked. Do you have other configuration? Try putting a log statement in the `onStartup` to see whether it's ever being called.

Comment: no other configurations. i did try your suggestion and put System.out.println("calling onStartup");. It did not get called. any ideas why this is so?

Comment: Are you sure that the `spring-web` jar is on your runtime classpath? That's where the `SpringServletContainerInitializer`, which is supposed to scan for and invoke this class, is located. Also, you have the wrong XSL in your `web.xml`; you need version 3.0 in both places.

Comment: I've edited web.xml following your suggestion. spring-web.jar is under Maven Dependencies in my Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Maven Dependencies. is this enough or should it be configured in another way?

Comment: That's enough as long as the scope is correct (`compile` is probably what you need).

Comment: how do i run compile? i've triend checking 'Run As' but found no compile

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36193/discussion-between-chrylis-and-user571099)

Answer (score 0):

Your are linking to `hello-page.html` (<a href="**hello-page.html**">), but controller is mapped to `hello-page` (@RequestMapping(value = "/**hello-page**")) without `.html` postfix.

Also, for all your links you should use [c:url](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html) or [spring:url](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/UrlTag.html) tags.

Comment: tried @RequestMapping(value="/hello-page.html"), but the 404 error still persisted

Comment: And waht is the mapping of DispatcherServlet? Is it mapped to .html?

Comment: dispatcherservlet mapping is mapped to handle all requests, it's in WebAppInitializer.java

Answer (score 0):

If I was yourself, I would use the JSTL `<c:url` tag within your `<a href="" />` HTML tag.

So this would be:

```
<a href="<c:url value="hello-page"/>">Access Hello</a>
```

In addition, have your tried putting a forward slash in front of `hello-page` within the `<a>` tag? That also may solve your problem. (Removing the `.html` as your Controller is mapped to `hello-page`).

Comment: tried c:url and putting a forward slash, still did not work I'm afraid

Comment: If it isn't that then I must be in your Spring XML configuration; that is more likely to be the issue. Please show us your XML config.

Comment: the web app uses java-based configuration, so no XML config files exist for this one

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial:

http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-creation-of-simple-controller-with-java-based-config/

and was facing same issue. After researching I found that any `web-server` tries to find `web.xml` first, inside `WEB-INF` folder because it is the default deployment descriptor of a web-application.

In this case if `web.xml` is already there and you are defining your own `WebApplicationInitializer`, the `web-server` will not be able to use it because it has already found one.

So remove the `web.xml` file from the project and then run again.

Answer (score 0):

**WebAppInitializer.java** required below change.

```
 servletDynamic.addMapping("*.html");
```